# how to set zoom default using Css

Tags: html, css, zooming

```css
body{
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width:80%;
  color: #264653;
  position: relative;
}
#photo{
  border-radius: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 50px;
}
.left1{
  margin-top: 10%;
  background-color: #264653;
  width : 30%;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.left2{
  background-color: #264653;
  width : 30%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  padding-top: 25%;
  padding-left: 1.5%;
  color:white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-indent: 12px;
}
#title{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 31.5%;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding : 20px 175px;
  background-color: white;
  color:#264653;
}
.right{
  position: absolute;
  left:35%;
  top : 30%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 60%;
}
.article{
  display: block;
  background-color: #264653;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  width: 90%;
}

.annee{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15%;
  font-weight: bold;

}
```

The entire page when zoomed in way too much, everything is mashing into each other and its just not appearing as the original design including images and text.

**So how my webpage could appear with the same original design even with the zooming in?**

ps : here I add the code, I don't what's the problem, is it because I used "positio"

Answer (score 0):

Try making the website [Responsive](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Responsive Image</h2>
<p>When the CSS width property is set in a percentage value, the image will scale up and down when resizing the browser window. Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

<img src="img_girl.jpg" style="width:100%;">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't posted any code about your design, and your question is very general and it depends on your layout and styles that you use. here I posted a code and have some tips that could help you to solve your problem:

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #4b8ff0;
    color: white;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.container::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both
}

.leftTag {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 360px;
    background-color: #7f000a;
}

.rightTag {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
    height: 360px;
    background-color: #123456;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 854px) {
    .container {
        width: 750px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>zoom-file</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="leftTag">
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor similique vel ex, quis sint at accusamus labore sit.</p>
       </div>
       
       <div class="rightTag">
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis reiciendis fuga veritatis quaerat praesentium ipsa saepe commodi placeat atque provident vitae illum molestiae, adipisci repudiandae nesciunt ducimus sit ipsam ea quibusdam architecto ut qui beatae! Numquam vel mollitia, expedita iure est. Est voluptatibus, minima obcaecati accusamus, libero aperiam fugiat, repellat a hic deleniti quia maxime.</p>
       </div>
   </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

here I posted a simple container that have two columns that are besides each other with "float" property. but when you zoom in the page you could inspect that the width of ".container" tag is changed to 750px at some level of zoom. this is because of "@media" rule of css that you can read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

other links that are usefule are about javascript "resize" method and window width that could help you:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp

the last thing that I could add is that it is better to use relative units (like width:45%) to force the tags to have relative size to their parents. in this way you need lower changes on different "window size". because when you zoom in or out actually the browser window width is changed.

Comment: here I add the code, and I'm just a beginner in Css maybe I could be missing some attributes

Answer (score 0):

HI @issou Ok so to solve your problem you have to change all your unite PX into rem because when you set value with unite PX you fix it to be for example 16px whatever the zoom , but when you set for example

```
1rem =16px by default so 1rem it will be responsive with the zoom ,
also 
you can change:
1rem =16px in the ::root element of your page HTML.
```

I hope that helpful, if I don't understand your question  let me know   ("_")

Comment: yeah keep % but change PX to rem